# Laravel how to Query Rows by Column in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

In Laravel, I can get the rows from a selected column in MySQL by a Laravel query.

```
$data = DB::query('select engagements from csv2');
```

However, I wonder how can I write this using Eloquent?

Comment: I google `php eloquent` and found this http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data = Model::get(array('engagements'));
```

For example if I only want to get the E-mail for a user;

```
$email = User::get(array('email'));
```

Comment: Can i query rows that only has value on it

Answer (score 1):

Egill's answer works, however I find the below more readable.

```
$email = User::select('email')->get();
```

And for your follow up question.

> Can i query rows that only has value on it

```
 $email = User::select('email')
    ->where('email', '!=', '')
    ->get();
```